# "Reputation to the max" isn't working fully

Tags: bug, reputation, moderation, unicoins, april-fools

I just bought "Reputation to the max". I bought this first, because I really want to help the cleanup of the vote-to-close queue, which, despite the efforts I've been hearing about, is still quite large. According to SO, my reputation is now 15,750, but that queue still says I need at least 3k rep to review! That is clearly a bug!

Comment: DONT DOWNVOTE HIM , ITS APRIL FIRST EVERYTHING

Comment: Well, is April 1st also opposite day? If so, upvote everything you would usually downvote, and downvote everything you would usually upvote!

Comment: I also had an issue where my rep is still less than Jon Skeet's even after multiplying mine by 10 and dividing everyone else's by 10... what's the deal???

Comment: Why did someone just upvote this? I definitely thought it was amusing at the time, but why would anyone be looking at it *now*?

Answer (score -1):

yOU Need to apply the unicoin meta-voucher (28B)